# Change decimal to integer in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to round off decimal value to integer in SQL
**Eg : 748.444645 to 749**

Comment: `749`? Are you sure?

Comment: Nothing on Google for 'SQL how to round'?

Comment: Lookup `ceil()`, maybe that's what you want.

Comment: Which DB? Usually you can use 2 functions, depending what you need:
`FLOOR( 748.444645 ) -> 748
    CEILING( 748.444645 ) -> 749`

Comment: And what do you ecpect for 748.5 and 748.50001? Standard SQL supports `cast(col as decimal(10,0))` for rounding and `cast(col as integer)` for truncating.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to round.  You want the ceiling.  In most databases, this would be a function called `ceil()` or `ceiling()`:

```
select ceiling(col)
```

Answer (score 0):

for round off decimal value to an integer

you need to use [ceiling()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysqlserver.asp?filename=trysql_func_sqlserver_ceiling) function of sql.

for eg: SELECT **CEILING(27.445)** AS CeilValue;

the answer will be **28**

if you want 748 as result use Floor() please check below image I have executed the query.

- FLOOR() function returns the largest integer value that is smaller than or equal to a number.

[image]

if you want 749 as a result use Ceiling please check the image below

- CEILING() function returns the smallest integer value that is larger than or equal to a number.

[image]

Comment: But this value should be "Select CEILING(748.344645)" to **748**

Comment: @Logesh, I'm confused; so what is you expected output, 748 or 749? If 748 please edit your question.

Comment: But for `CEILING(-27.445)`it will be `-27`, this might not what the OP wants :-9

Comment: @LogeshI have updated my answer with description and query execution let me know this clarifies or not.